# How to read data from excel or csv file based on data availability?

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have two kind of files, excel and csv which I am using to read data with two permanent columns : Question, Answer and two temporary columns which may or may not be present Word and Replacement.

I have made different functions to read data from csv and excel file which will be called based on the extension of file.

Is there a way to read the data from temporary columns(Word and Replacement) based on when they are present and when they are not. Please see the function definition below :

1) For CSV file:

```
def read_csv_file(path):
    quesData = []
    ansData = []
    asciiIgnoreQues = []
    qWithoutPunctuation = []
    colnames = ['Question','Answer']
    data = pandas.read_csv(path, names = colnames)
    quesData = data.Question.tolist()
    ansData = data.Answer.tolist()
    qWithoutPunctuation = quesData

    qWithoutPunctuation = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in qWithoutPunctuation]

    for x in qWithoutPunctuation:
        asciiIgnoreQues.append(x.encode('ascii','ignore'))

    return asciiIgnoreQues, ansData, quesData
```

2) Function to read excel data:

```
def read_excel_file(path):
    book = open_workbook(path)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    quesData = []
    ansData = []
    asciiIgnoreQues = []
    qWithoutPunctuation = []

    for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        quesData.append(sheet.cell(row,0).value)
        ansData.append(sheet.cell(row,1).value)

    qWithoutPunctuation = quesData
    qWithoutPunctuation = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in qWithoutPunctuation]

    for x in qWithoutPunctuation:
        asciiIgnoreQues.append(x.encode('ascii','ignore'))

    return asciiIgnoreQues, ansData, quesData
```

Comment: Did you consider `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.read_excel`? They will read automatically based on what columns are present.

Comment: @tmrlvi, I have used pandas.read_csv in reading csv function but the column headers have to be provided in colnames. But what if I dont have Words and Replacement cloumns ?

Comment: You don't have to provide them.If you don't, `pandas` infer the names. Or is it that your data doesn't contain headers?

Comment: My data contains headers (Question, Answer, Word, Replacement). So you are saying if I don't provide **colnames** in code, pandas will read from second row ?

Comment: Anyway it reads from the second line, unless you provide `header=None`

Comment: Can you tell me how can I implement in the code snippet I have given above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you tried to achieve, but reading and transforming you data, the `pandas` way, is done as following:

```
def read_file(path, typ):
    if typ == "excel":
        df = pd.read_excel(path, sheetname=0) # Default is zero
    else: # Assuming "csv". You can make it explicit
        df = pd.read_csv(path)

    qWithoutPunctuation = df["Question"].apply(lambda s: ''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation))
    df["asciiIgnoreQues"] = qWithoutPunctuation.apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii','ignore'))

    return df

# Call it like this:
read_data("file1.csv","csv")
read_data("file2.xls","excel")
read_data("file2.xlsx","excel")
```

This will return you a `DataFrame` with the columns `["Question","Answer", "asciiIgnoreQues"]` in case your data didn't include `Word` and `Replacement`, and `["Question", "Word", "Replacemen", "Answer", "asciiIgnoreQues"]` if it did.

Note that I've used `apply` which enables you to run a function elementwise on all the series.